# How to display multiple images

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Using ASP.NET Core 6 I'm trying to build a web app like Pinterest and I can't display multiple images. This is a web API and I need to do it without a view.

The only thing I found is `return File(...)` but this way only returns one image.

Comment: What has Swagger todo with it?

Comment: Have you tried returning a collection such as `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>`? Also, as Adam Carr's answer said, returning one at a time is not bad and tbh is preferable for web dev. Imagine a page with 5 images: would you want 4 good/1 broken image link or *all* 5 images to be broken for whatever API or request specific reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning one image is not necessarily a bad thing.  You need to think on how to compose the page.

If you have images which are related to a topic. You can have an additional endpoint that will return an array of image id's associated with that topic.  You can loop over the images in the array adding image tags pointing to the end point.  Don't forget to make sure to pass the image identifier.

The browser and API will deal with loading the images from the server.